# Checkbox dependencies javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

my job is to implement a catalog. It consists of about 100 checkboxes. These are dependent on each other.
For example: If the checkbox with ID=4 is selected, the checkboxes with ID=56 and ID=27 must be disabled.

Does a framework or something similar exist to implement this?

Thank you!

Comment: No but you can code it yourself. Should be fairly simple to code

Comment: Use a mapper to have a tracking of parent and dependent checkboxes. This you can use to disable.

Comment: You should provide us with some HTML you already coded

Comment: @garryman there are only normal html checkboxes with ID and classes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there is any js module already there for this, but you can try the below approach by creating a mapping and disabling the checkboxes.

```js
var checkboxMap = {
  "4": [56, 27]
}

function disableCheckboxes(id) {
  for (i in checkboxMap[id]) {
    document.getElementById(checkboxMap[id][i]).disabled = true;
  }
}

var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName("checkbox")

//adding event listener

for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
  checkboxes[i].addEventListener("change", function(e) {
    if (e.target.checked) {
      disableCheckboxes(e.target.id);
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<label for="4">id: 4
<input type="checkbox" id="4" class="checkbox" />
</label>

<label for="56">id: 56
<input type="checkbox" id="56" class="checkbox" />
</label>

<label for="27">id: 27
<input type="checkbox" id="27" class="checkbox" />
</label>
```